# How do I delete an element of a nested associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of the form Array ( [test1] => Array ( [test2] => Array ( [test3] => Hello ) ) ), I need to create a function to which I need to pass the key in the array and it will delete it. For example, remove('test2');
Through recursion, I'm trying to find this element in the array and if there is one, I'm trying to delete it.

```
function del_key($key, array $arr) {
  if (isset($arr[$searchKey])) {
            unset($arr[$searchKey]);
        }
        foreach ($arr as $key => &$param) {
            if (is_array($param)) {
                self::del_key($searchKey, $param);
            }
          }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so where's the actual _recursion_ in your attempt?

Comment: function dell_key($searchKey, array $arr, $k = 'i')
    {

            if (isset($arr[$searchKey])) {
                unset($arr[$searchKey]);
            }
            foreach ($arr as $key => &$param) {
                if (is_array($param)) {
                    self::dell_key($searchKey, $param, $k = 'r');
                }
              }
        }
    }

Comment: @Him4enko please [edit] your post if you have updates or new code for us. As you can see, it's hard to read code like that in the comments, and it doesn't belong there anyway. Your actual question should contain everything needed. See also [ask] and the [tour] for more guidance on how to use this site, since I can see from your empty profile that you didn't take up this advice when it was offered to you before posting anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not show the whole function, therefore it is not easy to understand it.
Anyway, a recursive function that does the job is as follows:

```
function array_remove_recursive(array &$array, array $keys_to_remove)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (in_array($value, $keys_to_remove, true)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            array_remove_recursive($value, $keys_to_remove);
        }
    }
}
```

It can remove multiple keys in one scan.

If you need it as class method just correct the recursion call accordingly

Comment: Still does not delete.

Comment: sorry my fault, in the if I was checking the value instead of the key, I corrected the function.
The previous version was deleting the element with the matching value